# How to get SimpleXmlElement attribute's value?

Tags: php, simplexml

I have this XML code:

```xml
<w:footerReference w:type="default" r:id="rId6"/>
```

In PHP I have this code:

```php
// $footer is a SimpleXMLElement, contain the code above

foreach ($footer->attributes() as $attr_name => $attr_value) {
    dd($attr_name." = ".$attr_value);
}
```

And the `foreach` isn't run.

I tried this too:

```php
$type = 'type';
$footer->attributes()->$type; // empty string

$wtype = 'w:type';
$footer->attributes()->$wtype; // empty string
```

Of course I can convert XML to string and do some regex magic, but it isn't a good way in my opinion.

**UPDATE:**

Here is the entire XML document code:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<w:document xmlns:wpc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingCanvas" 
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
    xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" 
    xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" 
    xmlns:m="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math" 
    xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" 
    xmlns:wp14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingDrawing" 
    xmlns:wp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing" 
    xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" 
    xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" 
    xmlns:w14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordml" 
    xmlns:w15="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2012/wordml" 
    xmlns:wpg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingGroup" 
    xmlns:wpi="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingInk" 
    xmlns:wne="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml" 
    xmlns:wps="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingShape" mc:Ignorable="w14 w15 wp14">
    <w:body>
        <w:sectPr w:rsidR="00654EDA">
            <w:footerReference w:type="default" r:id="rId6"/>
        </w:sectPr>
    </w:body>
</w:document>
```

How can I access the `w:type` and `r:id` attributes values?

Comment: i would help you but i get error : "Namespace prefix w for type on footerReference is not defined" when i try `$html = '<w:footerReference w:type="default" r:id="rId6"/>';$dom = new \SimpleXMLElement($html);`

Comment: @AndreaManzi : I updated the question with the entire XML code. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass attribute namespace as paramter of `attributes`

```
$type = $footer->attributes("http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main")->type;

$id = $footer->attributes("http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships")->id;
```

the same with foreach

```
foreach ($footer->attributes("http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main") as $attr_name => $attr_value) {
    dd($attr_name." = ".$attr_value);
}
foreach ($footer->attributes("http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships") as $attr_name => $attr_value) {
    dd($attr_name." = ".$attr_value);
}
```